# How to change Ctrl + <Keypad Key> behavior?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I often use my keypad keys for navigation. I'd like to change my keyboard behavior so that, for example,

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>(keypad) page up</kbd>

functions the same as

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>page up</kbd>.

There's a similar option in Keyboard Layout -> Options -> Miscellaneous compatibility options that makes <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>(keypad) page up</kbd> behave the same as <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>page up</kbd>, but there is no such option for control. How can I do this?

Comment: By keypad do you mean the arrow keys or the number pad?

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on the version one is using.

For Ubuntu 20.04, this is how to **set keyboard shortcuts**:

> To change the key or keys to be pressed for a keyboard shortcut:
>
> 1. Open the Activities overview and start typing Settings.
> 2. Click on Settings.
> 3. Click Keyboard Shortcuts in the sidebar to open the panel.
> 4. Click the row for the desired action. The Set shortcut window will be shown.
> 5. Hold down the desired key combination, or press Backspace to reset, or press Esc to cancel.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en